# ESP32 SocketIO Client is not connecting to Flask-SocketIO Server

Tags: c++, esp32, python, websocket

I'm trying to connect a ESP32 client using `SocketIO` with a `Flask-SocketIO` server and it's not getting connected.
The server uses SSL. The local server address is `https://192.168.1.137:3000`.Is the `https` causing issue here?

The following is the output from the ESP32 in the serial monitor. Note that esp32 successfully connects to the wifi.

```
> ["myEvent",{"now":95506}]
> [IOc] Disconnected!
> [IOc] Disconnected!
> [IOc] Disconnected!
> ...
```

Esp32 code:

```
/*
* WebSocketClientSocketIOack.ino
*/

#include <Arduino.h>

#include <WiFi.h>
#include <WiFiMulti.h>
#include <WiFiClientSecure.h>

#include <ArduinoJson.h>

#include <WebSocketsClient.h>
#include <SocketIOclient.h>

WiFiMulti WiFiMulti;
SocketIOclient socketIO;

#define USE_SERIAL Serial


void socketIOEvent(socketIOmessageType_t type, uint8_t * payload, size_t length) {
    switch(type) {
        case sIOtype_DISCONNECT:
            USE_SERIAL.printf("[IOc] Disconnected!\n");
            break;
        case sIOtype_CONNECT:
            USE_SERIAL.printf("[IOc] Connected to url: %s\n", payload);

            // join default namespace (no auto join in Socket.IO V3)
            socketIO.send(sIOtype_CONNECT, "/");
            break;
        case sIOtype_EVENT:
        {
            char * sptr = NULL;
            int id = strtol((char *)payload, &sptr, 10);
            USE_SERIAL.printf("[IOc] get event: %s id: %d\n", payload, id);
            if(id) {
                payload = (uint8_t *)sptr;
            }
            DynamicJsonDocument doc(1024);
            DeserializationError error = deserializeJson(doc, payload, length);
            if(error) {
                USE_SERIAL.print(F("deserializeJson() failed: "));
                USE_SERIAL.println(error.c_str());
                return;
            }

            String eventName = doc[0];
            USE_SERIAL.printf("[IOc] event name: %s\n", eventName.c_str());

            // Message Includes a ID for a ACK (callback)
            if(id) {
                // creat JSON message for Socket.IO (ack)
                DynamicJsonDocument docOut(1024);
                JsonArray array = docOut.to<JsonArray>();

                // add payload (parameters) for the ack (callback function)
                JsonObject param1 = array.createNestedObject();
                param1["now"] = millis();

                // JSON to String (serializion)
                String output;
                output += id;
                serializeJson(docOut, output);

                // Send event
                socketIO.send(sIOtype_ACK, output);
            }
        }
            break;
        case sIOtype_ACK:
            USE_SERIAL.printf("[IOc] get ack: %u\n", length);
            break;
        case sIOtype_ERROR:
            USE_SERIAL.printf("[IOc] get error: %u\n", length);
            break;
        case sIOtype_BINARY_EVENT:
            USE_SERIAL.printf("[IOc] get binary: %u\n", length);
            break;
        case sIOtype_BINARY_ACK:
            USE_SERIAL.printf("[IOc] get binary ack: %u\n", length);
            break;
    }
}

void setup() {
    //USE_SERIAL.begin(921600);
    USE_SERIAL.begin(115200);

    //Serial.setDebugOutput(true);
    USE_SERIAL.setDebugOutput(true);

    // USE_SERIAL.println();
    // USE_SERIAL.println();
    // USE_SERIAL.println();

      // for(uint8_t t = 4; t > 0; t--) {
      //     USE_SERIAL.printf("[SETUP] BOOT WAIT %d...\n", t);
      //     USE_SERIAL.flush();
      //     delay(1000);
      // }

    WiFiMulti.addAP("ssid", "mypass");

    //WiFi.disconnect();
    while(WiFiMulti.run() != WL_CONNECTED) {
        delay(100);
    }

    String ip = WiFi.localIP().toString();
    USE_SERIAL.printf("[SETUP] WiFi Connected %s\n", ip.c_str());

    // server address, port and URL
    socketIO.begin("192.168.1.137", 3000, "/socket.io/?EIO=4");

    // event handler
    socketIO.onEvent(socketIOEvent);
}

unsigned long messageTimestamp = 0;
void loop() {
    socketIO.loop();

    uint64_t now = millis();

    if(now - messageTimestamp > 2000) {
        messageTimestamp = now;

        // creat JSON message for Socket.IO (event)
        DynamicJsonDocument doc(1024);
        JsonArray array = doc.to<JsonArray>();

        // add event name
        // Hint: socket.on('event_name', ....
        array.add("myEvent");

        // add payload (parameters) for the event
        JsonObject param1 = array.createNestedObject();
        param1["now"] = (uint32_t) now;

        // JSON to String (serializion)
        String output;
        serializeJson(doc, output);

        // Send event
        socketIO.sendEVENT(output);

        // Print JSON for debugging
        USE_SERIAL.println(output);
    }
}
```

Server code (Removed unrelated parts):

```
from flask import Flask, render_template, Blueprint, current_app, request, session, url_for, render_template
from flask_socketio import SocketIO, emit

from threading import Thread
from queue import Queue
import logging

loggerPath = baseUrl + "logs/appLog.log"
os.makedirs(os.path.dirname(loggerPath), exist_ok=True)
with open(loggerPath, "a") as f:
    logging.basicConfig( level=logging.INFO,
        # format='%(asctime)s - %(name)s - %(levelname)s - %(message)s',
        format='%(levelname)s - %(message)s',
        filename=loggerPath
    )   
bp = Blueprint('audio', __name__, static_folder='static',
            template_folder='templates')
app = Flask(__name__)

async_mode = "threading"

socketio = SocketIO(app, cors_allowed_origins="*", async_mode=async_mode)

@socketio.on('myEvent')
def test_connect(data): 
    logging.info("receiving")

def runApp():
    try:
        certificatePath = os.getenv('BASE_URL')+"SSL/"
        key = certificatePath+"localhost.key"
        certificate = certificatePath+"localhost.crt"
        context = ssl.SSLContext(ssl.PROTOCOL_TLS_SERVER)
        context.load_cert_chain(certificate, key)
        ip = socket.gethostbyname(socket.gethostname())
        socketio.run(app, host=ip, port=3000,ssl_context=context)
    except Exception as e:
        logging.error("Exception occurred in: "+__file__, exc_info=True)

q = Queue()
t = Thread(target=wrapper, args=(q, runApp), daemon=True)
t.start()
```

Comment: have you examined the ESP32BasicExample sketch?

Comment: Above code is from the WebSockets_Generic\examples\esp32\ESP32_WebSocketClientSocketIO\ESP32_WebSocketClientSocketIO.ino

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is version Socketio issue,I have successfully connected .
This installed version
Werkzeug 2.0.0
Flask 2.3.3
Flask-SocketIO 4.3.1
python-engineio 3.13.2
python-socketio 4.6.0